# I am not able to show image in the Edit Modal

Tags: jquery, laravel, image, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

This is the body code and HTML which is sending data to script.

```
@foreach($products as $product)
                            @if($product->category == "Starters")
                                <div class="food-item white">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
                                            <div class="rest-logo pull-left">
                                                <a class="restaurant-logo pull-left" href="#"><img src="images/{{$product->image}}" alt="Food logo"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Logo -->
                                            <div class="rest-descr">
                                                <h6><a href="#">{{$product->name}}</a></h6>
                                                <p> Burgers, American, Sandwiches, Fast Food, BBQ</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end:Description -->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end:col -->
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 pull-right item-cart-info"> <span class="price pull-left">${{$product->price}}</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn btn-secondary pull-right" data-id="{{$product->id}}" data-name="{{$product->name}}" data-price="{{$product->price}}" data-image="{{$product->image}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal">&#43;</a> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end:row -->
                                </div>
                                @endif
                        @endforeach
```

This is the script:

```
<script>
$('#product-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    // var driver_id = button.data('driverid');
    var name = button.data('name');
    var price = button.data('price');
    var image = button.data('image');
    var id = button.data('id');
    var modal = $(this)

    // modal.find('.modal-body #driver_id').val(driver_id);
    modal.find('.modal-body #name').val(name);
    modal.find('.modal-body #price').val(price);
    modal.find('.modal-body #image').val(image);
    modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id);



});
```

And this is the part of the Bootstrap Modal where I want to show the image:

```
<input type="image" name="image" id="image">
```

It only gets the value by which the image is saved in THE database. But I want to show the image.

Comment: what do you have in the database for the `image` field?

Comment: I am using faker in migration to save images.
This is the command to save images:
'image' => $faker->image('public/images',400,300,null,false),
and it saves like "ad5c6553f969c459b8d8c5dcfee3490b.jpg".
May be its a extension.

Comment: is this saving the image in `storage/app/public/images`? and if so do you have the storage symlink setup for `public/storage => storage/app/public`?

Comment: It's storing the images in public/images.

Comment: and it is storing the images in database by there names. if image name is image1.jpg then in database its storing image1.jpg. By their names.

Comment: if you want to show the image next to this input you would need an `img` tag somewhere

Comment: @lagbox i changed the code with: data-image="{{asset('/images/'). $product->image}}" and in script: modal.find('.modal-body #image').attr('src',image);
Now input tag is getting imagesad5c6553f969c459b8d8c5dcfee3490b.jpg. It should be images/ad5c6553f969c459b8d8c5dcfee3490b.jpg

Comment: "/" is missing but don't know from where.

Comment: @lagbox what should be change in this code to put the "/"?

Comment: If using JavaScript, +"/"+